# Apache - deny non-local requests that match a specific URL pattern

Tags: apache, webserver, config, directive

I need to configure my Apache (2.4) in a way, that it prevents answering specific requests

I have an application that runs on a server `myapplication.com`.
Browsing the application triggers some further ajax requests on the server, having the pattern `myapplication.com/abc`. These kind of "abc"-requests must be prohibited, when being called from a different context then this one. Thus, is should not be possible to call this request in a different tab. Neither should it be possible to call these requests outside a browser context, for example via curl or wget or any non-browser http client.

The directive must look something like this

```
<If "Request has not been triggered as ajax from within my application" &&  %{REQUEST_URL} contains 'abc' ">
  Require all denied 
</If>
```

---

This directive causes an error and I dont know why, changing `=~` to `!~` is semantically false but does not cause an error.

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} !~ /myapplication.com/ && %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /abc/ ">
  Require all denied
</If>
```

What can be wrong with that?

Any help debugging the apache config would also be appreciated - I don't get any information why this directive causes errors.

Comment: In your example /abc is not a query string, did you mean to check %{REQUEST_URI}?

> I don't get any information why this directive causes errors.

What errors?

> Neither should it be possible to call these requests outside a browser context, for example via curl or wget or any non-browser http client.

Anything you can check can be inserted by a malicious user.

Answer (score 1):

Any [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) call made from `myapplication.com` in browser will contain `myapplication.com` as [`referer` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer).

The following apache conf snippet will block requests which referrer isn't `myapplication.com`.

```
<Location "/abc">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!myapplication.com"
    RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
</Location>
```

This configuration requires `mod_rewrite` which can be enabled with `a2enmod rewrite` if not already done.

Comment: I would prefer doing that with an If Directive